# Private applications cannot request a Request Token error while connecting Xero web API

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, xero-api

I am following below VB.Net example application.
https://github.com/SuperRoo/Xero_Asp_VB_Net_Connection_Example

The code looks promising. But when I run the application, below line gives an exception.

```
Dim token As RequestToken = SessionManager.XeroSession.GetRequestToken(callbackUri.Uri)
```

> Exception Details: DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.OAuthException: Private
>   applications cannot request a Request Token

FYI: I couldn't get anything from this forum thread.
https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/6639946

Somebody help me to resolve this issue. please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. When I created the application in Xero Developer Centre ([api.xero.com](http://api.xero.com)), I selected the "private" option. But the example code above is a public type.

Now I have deleted the old application in Xero Developer Centre and created the "public" type application and used the new consumer key and consumer secret. Now the application is connecting.